IF Else issue with *.CMD / Batch Script using File Compare (FC)
I've been working on a quick *.CMD file to compare 5 local hard drive files to 5 network files (which should be identical) with UNC folder location.
I've gotten what I thought should work, but keep getting an error, "else was expected at this time."
Is there something wrong with my IF / ELSE or messing something up?  This has me scratching my head.  I'd normally do something this simple in Python, but will be running it on several computers that don't have Python installed.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: List of file names to compare
set file1=TestFile1.txt
set file2=TestFile2.txt
set file3=TestFile3.txt
set file4=TestFile4.txt
set file5=TestFile5.txt

:: Local folder path
set localFolder=C:\localFolderLocation

:: UNC path
set uncFolder=\\uncFolderLocation

:: Function to compare files
:compareFiles
set file1Path=%localFolder%\%file1%
set file2Path=%localFolder%\%file2%
set file3Path=%localFolder%\%file3%
set file4Path=%localFolder%\%file4%
set file5Path=%localFolder%\%file5%

:: Loop through the files
for %%F in (%file1% %file2% %file3% %file4% %file5%) do (
  fc /b "%localFolder%\%%F" "%uncFolder%\%%F" >nul
  if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
    echo %%F matches (0)
  ) else (
    echo %%F is different (1)
  )
)
goto :EOF

:: Call the function
call :compareFiles


I've tried changing the "equ" in the IF line to == and that has no effect.  Is this a problem with enabledelayedexpansion?  Any advice?  Is there some way to step through a BATCH script to execute it line by line to find the cause?  I haven't scripted in Batch for years.
Thanks for any help or advice!

why echo %%F matches (0) a closing parens is matching an opening one, not the one you suppose. either remove it, or escape it echo %%F matches (0^). echoing parens within a block commands inside parens may lead to ... problems

one more think, is this the real code? I see you are are using :: as comments. though I don't see any :: comment inside the for block, you may find some side effects about using that syntax inside blocks instead of rem

Inside a command block beginning with ( the next found ) not being inside a double quoted argument string or escaped with ^ for being interpreted as literal character is interpreted as the end of the command block. There is in posted batch code:
echo %%F matches (0)

The closing round bracket is interpreted in this case as end of the true branch command block of the command IF. The next ) left to else is interpreted as the end of the command block of the command FOR. The command else is therefore not expected at this time as it does not belong to an IF condition.
The working code with exit code evaluation of fc from lowest to highest:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem List of file names to compare
set "file1=TestFile1.txt"
set "file2=TestFile2.txt"
set "file3=TestFile3.txt"
set "file4=TestFile4.txt"
set "file5=TestFile5.txt"

rem Local folder path
set "localFolder=C:\localFolderLocation"

rem UNC path
set "uncFolder=\\uncFolderLocation"

rem Loop through the files
for %%G in ("%file1%" "%file2%" "%file3%" "%file4%" "%file5%") do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\fc.exe /B "%localFolder%\%%~G" "%uncFolder%\%%~G" 1>nul 2>nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%G matches (0^)
    ) else if not errorlevel 2 (
        echo %%G is different (1^)
    ) else (
        if not exist "%localFolder%\%%~G" echo ERROR: Missing file: "%localFolder%\%%~G"
        if not exist "%uncFolder%\%%~G" echo ERROR: Missing file: "%uncFolder%\%%~G"
    )
)
endlocal

Another solution with exit code evaluation of fc from highest to lowest:
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem List of file names to compare
set "file1=TestFile1.txt"
set "file2=TestFile2.txt"
set "file3=TestFile3.txt"
set "file4=TestFile4.txt"
set "file5=TestFile5.txt"

rem Local folder path
set "localFolder=C:\localFolderLocation"

rem UNC path
set "uncFolder=\\uncFolderLocation"

rem Loop through the files
for %%G in ("%file1%" "%file2%" "%file3%" "%file4%" "%file5%") do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\fc.exe /B "%localFolder%\%%~G" "%uncFolder%\%%~G" 1>nul 2>nul
    if errorlevel 2 (
        if not exist "%localFolder%\%%~G" echo ERROR: Missing file: "%localFolder%\%%~G"
        if not exist "%uncFolder%\%%~G" echo ERROR: Missing file: "%uncFolder%\%%~G"
    ) else if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%G is different (1^)
    ) else echo %%G matches (0^)
)
endlocal

This code works with any file/folder names including something like Development & Test 100% (!) containing characters like &%!() which require enclosing the entire file names in " and a disabled delayed variable expansion. The exclamation mark in the file name would be interpreted as beginning/end of a delayed expanded variable reference if delayed variable expansion would be enabled unnecessarily on processing the command lines.
There should be read in this answer at least the issue chapters:

Issue 1: File/folder argument strings not enclosed in quotes
Issue 2: Usage of a command block for a single command
Issue 6: Batch file depends on environment defined outside
Issue 7: Usage of letters ADFNPSTXZadfnpstxz as loop variable

These issue chapters explain most of the modifications applied on batch file code.
:: is the beginning of an invalid label. Lines beginning with : after zero or more normal spaces or horizontal tabs are ignored on parsing a command line by the Windows Command Processor cmd.exe except a GOTO or a CALL with a label is currently executed. Labels are not supported inside a command block beginning with ( and ending with matching ). That means also :: is not supported inside (…). The usage of a line beginning with : after zero or more leading spaces/tabs inside a command block results in undefined behavior on execution of the batch file. It can by chance work on test, but it can also completely fail now or later. :: should not be used for comments for that reason. There is the remark command REM for comments. Please note that cmd.exe first parses the entire command line with REM before the command REM is recognized. So be careful with characters like !%&)<>| in comments with command REM at the beginning. Best avoid them in comments.
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

cmd /?
echo /?
endlocal /?
fc /?
for /?
if /?
rem /?
set /?
setlocal /?

Other recommended pages:

Microsoft documentation about Using command redirection operators
SS64 documentation about FC.exe from A-Z index of Windows CMD commands
It has a description of the exit codes returned by this Windows command.
How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?
Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file
Difference between Dynamic variables and Environment variables in CMD

There should be never used %ERRORLEVEL% or !ERRORLEVEL! in a batch file. There should be always used the syntax as described by the help of command IF. An evaluation on a specific exit code value like 5 of a command or executable can be done with:
if not errorlevel 6 if errorlevel 5 echo The dynamic variable ERRORLEVEL has value 5.

